# Remove hidden fields depending on file deleted using jquery

Tags: jquery

Following on from a question I just asked and was replied to satisfactorily:

When I upload a file, I programatically generate hidden fields in a form, as follows:

```
<!-- first file uploaded -->
<input type="hidden" class="file" id="file-1" name="file-1" value="quote_202Hillside.pdf">
<input type="hidden" class="filesize" id="filesize-1" name="filesize-1" value="104246">
<input type="hidden" class="filethumbnailurl" id="filethumbnailurl-1" name="filethumbnailurl-1" value="/images/website/icon-pdf.png">

<!-- second file uploaded -->
<input type="hidden" class="file" id="file-2" name="file-2" value="quote_39Queen.pdf">
<input type="hidden" class="filesize" id="filesize-2" name="filesize-2" value="114045">
<input type="hidden" class="filethumbnailurl" id="filethumbnailurl-2" name="filethumbnailurl-2" value="/images/website/icon-pdf.png">
```

Note how I have appended "-1" to the "id" attribute of the first file uploaded and "-2" to the "id" attribute of the second file. This should be useful for the next step, which I need help with:

Each uploaded file displays on the screen along with a "delete" button. Each respective delete button has a data-url attribute, e.g. as follows.

```
<button data-url="quote_39Queen.pdf">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

How do I remove all the hidden fields associated with that file?

I guess the pseudocode would go something like: On-click of the delete button, find the set of hidden fields where class="file" and "value" attribute matches the data-url value of the clicked button. Then, remove all hidden fields with the same "-1" or "-2" etc appendix in its "id" attribute.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked something out, though someone will probably have a more elegant way and I'd need to be careful about having similar id attributes in the dom for elements I don't want to remove.

```
var file = button.data('url');
var $x = $("input[value='" + file + "']");
var xno = $x.attr("id").split("-")[1];
$( "input[id*='-" + xno + "']" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Append file number to button attribute data-fileNo**

```
<button data-url="quote_39Queen.pdf" data-fileNo='1' onClick="removeHidden(this);">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

JS

```
function removeHidden(thisButton){
   var fileNo=$(thisButton).attr('data-fileNo') ; //2,3
   $('#file-'+fileNo).remove();
   $('#filesize-'+fileNo).remove();
   $('#filethumbnailurl-'+fileNo).remove();

}
```

Comment: Nice, but I can't change the way the button is generated at this stage, hence I cannot append new attributes or onClick function calls.